# AWS Neptune performance / Comparing to Neo4j AuraDB

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, performance, amazon-neptune

We use Neo4j AuraDB for our graph database but there we have issues with data upload. So, we decided to move to AWS Neptune using the migration tool.

We have 3.7M nodes and 11.2M relations in our database. The DB instance is db.r5.large with 2 CPUs and 16GiB RAM.

The same AWS Neptune OpenCypher queries are much slower than AuraDB Cypher queries (about 7-10 times slower). Also, we tried to rewrite the queries to Gremlin and test performance but it is still very slow. We have node and lookup indexes on AuraDB but we can't create them on AWS Neptune as it handles them automatically.

Is there any way to reach better performance on AWS Neptune?

**UPDATE:**

Example of Gremlin query:
`g.V().hasLabel('Member').has('address', eq('${address}')).outE('HAS').as('member_has').inV().as('token').hasLabel('Token').inE('HAS').as('other_member_has').outV().as('other_member').hasLabel('Member').where(__.select('member_has').where(neq('other_member_has'))).select('other_member', 'token').group().by(__.select('other_member').local(__.properties().group().by(__.key()).by(__.map(__.value())))).by(__.fold().project('member', 'number_of_tokens').by(__.unfold().select('other_member').choose(neq('cypher.null'), __.local(__.properties().group().by(__.key()).by(__.map(__.value()))))).by(__.unfold().select('token').count())).unfold().select(values).order().by(__.select('number_of_tokens'), desc).limit(20)`

Example of Cypher query:
`MATCH (member:Member { address: '${address}' })-[:HAS]->(token:Token)<-[:HAS]-(other_member:Member) RETURN PROPERTIES(other_member) as member, COUNT(token) AS number_of_tokens ORDER BY number_of_tokens DESC LIMIT 20`

Comment: Can you please share some example Gremlin and openCypher queries? Likewise can you say a bit about the data model? openCypher support is currently a preview and when the GA version launches you should see performance improvements. Also, are you running one query at a time or lots of queries at the same time?

Comment: F. e., we have `Member` and `Token` nodes and there is a `HAS` relation between them. We need to find the top 20 other members who have the same tokens as the specific member. 

`MATCH (member:Member { address: '${address}' })-[:HAS]->(token:Token)<-[:HAS]-(other_member:Member)
RETURN PROPERTIES(other_member) as member, COUNT(token) AS number_of_tokens
ORDER BY number_of_tokens DESC
LIMIT 20`
This query in AuraDB takes milliseconds but seconds on Neptune.

I tested it by running only one simple query at the same time.

Comment: You mentioned you also tried Gremlin - could you please also share that query?

Comment: One additional question - what is the Neptune Engine version that you are using?

Comment: I've added the same Gremlin query to the question (as it's too long). This is a simple query, but the difference is much better visible with some complex queries.

We use Neptune 1.0.5.1.R3

Comment: The newer Neptune engine versions do have several openCypher improvements (but are still preview level). That Gremlin query can be simplified quite a lot - I’m not surprised it may not perform well. The 1.1.0.0 engine is the current latest.  Are you able to retest the openCypher query on that engine version?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence how would you simplify that Gremlin query?

Comment: Is the Gremlin being generated using a tool or by hand? If it is meant to represent the openCypher query it can be greatly simplified. I will see if I can come up with a better example.

Comment: The current query was generated by a tool

Comment: OK thanks - that was my assumption from looking at the Gremlin.

Comment: @Pavlo Could you please share some more details regarding the issues which you faced on Neo4J, also the performance was better on Neptune?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, as of this moment, the openCypher support is a preview, not quite GA level. The more recent engine versions do have some significant improvements but more are yet to be delivered. As to the Gremlin query, tools that convert Cypher to Gremlin tend to build quite complex queries. I think the Gremlin equivalent to the Cypher query is going to look something like this.

```java
g.V().has('Member','address', address).as('m').
      out('HAS').hasLabel('Token').as('t').
      in('HAS').hasLabel('Member').as('om').
      where(neq('m')).
      group().
        by('om').
        by(select('t').count()).
      order(local).
        by(values,desc).
      limit(20)
```

and if you want all of the properties just add a `valueMap` as in:

```java
g.V().has('Member','address', address).as('m').
      out('HAS').hasLabel('Token').as('t').
      in('HAS').hasLabel('Member').as('om').
      where(neq('m')).
      group().
        by(select('om').valueMap(true)).
        by(select('t').count()).
      order(local).
        by(values,desc).
      limit(20)
```